# How to tell user there are no more results - infinite scroll

Tags: lists, feedback, pagination, infinite-scroll

We display search results with mechanism similar to infinite scroll. The only difference is that you can see more results by clicking "Show more" button at the end of the list - no automatic loading when you scroll down.

How to notify the user that there are no more results to display? Hide the "Show more" button? Disable it? Print a descriptive info?

Comment: You should replace the "Show more" button with **[this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HIH8W.jpg)**

Comment: I second @MonkeyZeus's notion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of displaying a "load more" button, you can easily just put a phrase that says something like "end" such as:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCVXkO.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Obviously, wording can change, but as long as they know that there is nothing more to show. Heck, even not displaying a button anymore can be sufficient enough.

Comment: If I saw that I would think I could still click the Load More button and get more data.. I'd lean towards just hiding the button like you mention at the end.

Comment: Sorry, those two were supposed to display two different states. It was just easier to show them all in one. For instance, load more will display if there is more to load, but end will show in place of the button when nothing else is left to show